# Set NSButtonCell Checkbox value in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have NSTableView with two columns,one with Checkbox and another with NSString.

i want to define all the Checkbox to true

i try to do it with:

```
    if (tableColumn == first) {
            return YES;
    }else if (tableColumn == second) {
            NSString *country = [array objectAtIndex:row];
            return [country lastPathComponent];
    }
```

but it give me crash when i start the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code is executing in `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:`. In that case, the table view only accepts objects, not primitive values.

Try changing `return YES` to `return [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`.